# Auto-close Ad Activities - is it worth it?

Tags: android, ads

By adding the attribute `android:noHistory` to Activity declaration in `Manifest`, it is possible to make the `finish()` method be called on an Activity as soon as the user clicks on it.

I think it is more user-friendly not to show an ad again if the user has already clicked on it.

Is anybody using this method? 
Or does auto-closing negatively impact the revenue?

Comment: Are you talking about *interstitial ads*?

Comment: Yes, interstitials like com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.